# Including specific external library to a jar file built by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, dependencies

I am trying to convert a multi module project build process from Ant to Gradle. 
We have a common module which is used by every other module. In common module I need these dependencies to be able compile it (by gradle build)

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    api 'org.json:json:20131018'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5'
    implementation 'org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.5.1'
    implementation 'org.python:jython:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

Some of modules should include all dependencies needed in runtime inside result jar files. Because of this I am adding the code of module dependencies to the jar file as well. Like below:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':core:common')
    compile project(':core:installer')
}

jar {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:common').sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:installer').sourceSets.main.output   
}
```

The problem is that I want to add external libraries to the jar file as well so that I have compelete jar file. It is possible to add external libraries by adding a line to jar above like this:

```
jar {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:common').sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:installer').sourceSets.main.output

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

}
```

But then I will have a large jar file containing all of dependencies in common module while some of them are not needed in my specific jar file. What I want is to add specific external libraries to jar file for example I want just add 'org.json:json:20131018' and  'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5' to library and ignore rest of dependencies. I couldn't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding the code below to jar:

```
jar {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:common').sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:installer').sourceSets.main.output
    def libraries =['httpclient-4.5.5.jar','json-20131018.jar']
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.
            findAll { libraries.contains(it.name)}.
            collect { zipTree(it) }      
}
```

But I think that still Gradle should offer a better solution to include or exclude external libraries to jar file.

I updated solution above little bit which I think it is a better way to do this because we don't need specify jar files. We can define a configuration like this:

```
configurations {
    runtimeLibraries
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':core:common')
    compile project(':core:installer')
    runtimeLibraries 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5', 'org.json:json:20131018'
}
```

Then we can update Jar task as below:

```
jar {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:common').sourceSets.main.output
    from project(':core:installer').sourceSets.main.output
    from configurations.runtimeLibraries.collect { zipTree(it) }
}
```

One diffference in result of those two methods is that with defining configuration gradle will recognize needed dependency and will add them to jar as well. For example if you are using commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1 as part of runtimeLibraries in created jar files you can find org.apache.oro packages which is used by commons-net